# Ansible k8s_facts/info throws openshift client not installed while running a playbook to fetch pod status

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am trying to get the status of pods running on k8 cluster.
I went through this document which [states](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html) that - "`Use the OpenShift Python client`"

Does that mean Openshift python client needs to be installed on the Master of K8 cluster or on the machine where ansible is installed and ansible scripts being invoked?

( I have  installed openshift client on the ansible server- however, still getting error that openshift client is not installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have installed openshift client on the ansible server- however, still getting error that openshift client is not installed

The answer is the same for every ansible module's dependency: it must be in the python that is configured as `ansible_python_interpreter` for the host against which that module is running. So, if your module is connecting to the k8s master, it must be in its python, if it's running against localhost, then it must be in the python you are using locally.

Be aware that "the python you are using locally" can be different from "the python that **ansible** is running under," especially if you have installed ansible via Homebrew or in its own virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for your response @mdaniel. I misread "host that executes this module" altogether. To summarise since my K8 cluster is remote - I have to install the requirements on k8 master then only k8s_info/facts will execute.
Confirmed my k8 master doesn't have openshift client installed :
```"module_args": {
      "dependencies": [
                "openshift",
                "requests"
            ]
        }
    },
    "mismatched": {},
    "not_found": [
        "openshift"
```
Can't thank you much,was trying all sorts of workarounds earlier on ansible master 4 day & a half now :(

Comment: *since my K8 cluster is remote - I have to install the requirements on k8 master* the answer depends on where the k8s credentials live -- if you have credentials on your local machine, you are free to use `delegate_to: localhost` since those k8s modules use the k8s api for management, which most certainly works from a remote machine; if you're taking advantage of the unauthenticated :8080 on the masters, then yes, I would guess you'll be required to use a python on the masters

Comment: Thanks for the value add @mdaniel - if credentials you mean are client key token et al.( which we use for K8 APIs) , that I do not have access to in this case- I can only ssh to the K8s master and then administer it. hence, in my case , I believe I wont be able to use delegate_to: localhost in this particular scenario. I wonder why this has not been discussed anywhere  or its so simple and I am making it complex